# TCL (expect): can't read "NF" (from awk): no such variable

Tags: awk, tcl, expect

Attempting to get the last word of the first line from a file.  Not sure why the following command:

`send "cat moo.txt | grep QUACK * | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' meow.txt >> bark.txt "`

is getting the error message `can't read "NF": no such variable`.

I can run the `awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' meow.txt >> bark.txt` snippet just fine on my machine.  Yet, when it runs in my `expect` script, it gives me that error.

Anyone know why expect doesn't recognize the `awk` built-in variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script is trying to expand the variable $NF with it's value before shooting that command through `send`. `$NF` isn't set in your shell since it's internal to awk, which hasn't had a chance to even run yet and so it's balking.

Try escaping that variable so it is treated as a string literal and `awk` will be able to use it when it comes time for `awk` to run:

```
send "cat moo.txt | grep QUACK * | awk 'NF>1{print \$NF}' meow.txt >> bark.txt "
```

Comment: The root of the problem is that the inner single quotes have no special meaning here. This is the same in the shell: whereas `'$FOO'` denotes the literal text `$FOO` (dollar sign, F, O, O). if we put it into double quotes: `"'$FOO'"`, the single quotes are just ordinary characters now: this denotes a single quote, value of `FOO` variable, single quote.

Comment: Tcl's equivalent to single quotes is `{`braces`}`.